# shape file (GIS) to text

Tags: file, gis, extract, shapes

How I can convert a shape file (GIS) to text?
or, How I can extract the information in a shape file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to write some code (and you will probably need to anyway as there is quite a bit of information in a shapefile, not all of it of interest for any given application)  check out [shapelib](http://shapelib.maptools.org/). It has bindings to many scripting languages.  It also builds dbfdump which is an executable for dumpint the dbffiles and shpdump that dumps the shp files.

Also of interest if you program in R is the maptools package.

Answer (score 2):

Mapwindow (http://mapwindow.org/) is free, open source, and has a convert shp to csv feature.

The csv files it produces are a little strange, but you should be able to manage.

Windows only.

Comment: I not find the option to convert to csv, but I use shape2earth plugin and convert to kml.

Answer (score 1):

look into [Gdal/ogr](http://gdal.org) bindings

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small app that can convert your shapefile to KML. Not exactly text but human readable and shareable across map applications. http://www.reimers.dk/files/folders/google_maps/entry328.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [MyGeodata GIS Data Formats and Corrdinate systems Converter - online](http://converter.mygeodata.eu). It uses OGR library mentioned here and alows to convert most used GIS formats to any other GIS format - so for you for example from ESRI ShapeFile to GeoJSON, GML, CSV or other text-based formats.

Answer (score 0):

There is a web page to view the contents:
http://webprocessresults.com/pgsActv/ShpDump.aspx

The same site offers a free desktop (windows) version:
http://webprocessresults.com/svcs/FreeStuff/FreeStuff.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using arcGIS and the shapefile is composed of several files you can try just opening the .dbf file in excel and saving it into another format (e.g. csv)- I've done this plenty of times and haven't had any ill effects and its a pretty quick and easy method of converting your shapefiles or doing any drastic edits saving as csv then reimporting them back into GIS for saving as a new shapefile. I will say this is and inelegant solution though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can find most of the shp (Shape File) format detailed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile. The full specification is here: http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf.

The `shp` file format is very simple, but be careful to mind that the length fields are for 16-bit words not 8-bit words. If you forget this you will spend a bit of time debugging what is going wrong when trying to parse out the records.

The `dbf` generally contains information associated with each shape. You can also parse the `dbf` file but you will have to roll your own reader. I have done it before, but the easiest may be to load the `dbf` up into some spreadsheet application and then save it as a `csv` file then load that. Also, if I remember correctly you have to be careful as some of the sites out there detailing the `dbf` can be a little off. It had something to do with a different version where some fields are a little different. So if you are rolling your own and you get stuck be mindful that you may be reading it correctly but it is differing from the specification you are using. I think the solution was that was to return to Google and search up some different docs and finally detailed the version I was reading.

*The `shp` and `dbf` are linked by the record index. The first record in the `shp` is linked with the first record in the `dbf` and so forth.*

You can fairly easily find format specifications for `dbf` such as here: http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/index.html. If you are willing to roll your own it will not be too much of a project.

In any regard no matter if you choose to roll your own reader for `dbf` or `shp` you will need to be mindful of the fields as some are big and others little endian byte ordering. I think this only applies to the `shp` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can open dbf file and copy content to another format, for example odt or XLSX.

For open dbf file recommend to use LibreOffice Calc

Answer (score 0):

If you are really in need of only the content in the shapefile., then looking for the .dbf file would give you a better view. You can directly open ".dbf" file with any excel viewer to look for the content in the shapefile.